# To enable the url rewrite with Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, url-rewriting

Want im trying to acheive,
    when url is hitting localhost/nap/ , internally it should call the url localhost/nap/inspect.do

To acheive this, Using Apache 2.2, following are the steps i followed,

1. Uncomment the line, LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
2. Added he following line in httpd.cnf file 

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nap/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nap/inspect.do$1 [L]

   restarted the apache server

   But this configuration doesnt help me

Answer (score 0):

You need only this in httpd.cnf file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/nap/$ /nap/inspect.do [L]
```

All requests with /localhost/nap/ will be redirected to run the file $DocumentRoot/nap/inspect.do script. L flag ignores all additional rewrite rules in the same file.